# How to add a variable to a href in a for loop in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I create eight divs in a for loop, and I want to add links each div to a different html page. And I also name the html page from 0~7. So how can I make the variable "i" into the href? Thanks!

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    counter[i] = increase * (i * 2);
    var div = $('<div class="node"><a id="link" href=i + ".html"><img src=archive/' + i + '.jpg width="200" height="200"/></a></div>');
    div.css({'top':yoffset,'left':innerWidth/8 * i});
    $('body').append(div);
    objects[i] = div;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean link it into the href ? Can you give a sample of how you expect the final href value to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
var div = $('<div class="node"><a id="link" href=i+".html"><img src=archive/'+i+'.jpg width="200" height="200"/></a></div>');
```

to

```
var div = $('<div class="node"><a id="link" href="'+i+'.html"><img src=archive/'+i+'.jpg width="200" height="200"/></a></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var div = $('<div class="node"><a id="link" href="' + i + '.html"><img src=archive/' + i + '.jpg width="200" height="200"/></a></div>');
```

This ought to make each link point to <i>.html.

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend creating the elements and setting the attributes instead of creating HTML code for the elements:

```
for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
  counter[i] = increase * (i * 2);
  var img = $('<img>', { src = 'archive/' + i + '.jpg', width: '200', height: '200' });
  var a = $('<a>', { id: 'link', href: i + '.html' }).append(img);
  var div = $('<div>', { 'class': 'node' }).append(a).css({'top':yoffset,'left':innerWidth/8 * i});
  $('body').append(div);
  objects[i] = div;
}
```